# Java Swing Calender or organizer

Tags: java, swing, jar, calendar

I want to add a `calender` or organizer to my `JPanel`. Such that I can add tasks to a date. Is there some Jar file that you peform? I know `JCalender` but it's without a `taskadd`.

Does someone have a experience with chronology?
[Download link](http://www.filebuzz.com/fileinfo/155703/chronology.html)

Comment: *"I know JCalender but it's without a taskadd."*  What is a "taskadd"?  Generally 3rd party APIs can be used by adding them to the class-path.  Never heard of this 'taskadd'.

Comment: taskadd i mean i can't add a task to a date.

Comment: By 'task' DYM 'method'?  Try to use the common terms.

Comment: Task ADD EDIT DELETE on a day!

Answer (score 1):

You can use JXDatePicker from swingx library(Or a JSpinner) and a TextArea/TextBox and a Submit JButton to add your tasks on Click of a Submit button in a database table or a file.

On selection of a date you can load the task from the database table in the TextArea/JTextField.

Comment: Is there no better option?